# An inequality for a side length of a triangle

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles

Let $\Delta ABC$ be a triangle, and $a,b,c$ are the side length $BC$, $CA$, $AB$, respectively. Assume that $c\leq b\leq a$. Let $h$ be the distance from point $A$ to $BC$. Show that $h\leq c\sqrt{1-\frac{c^2}{4b^2}}$.

I have noticed that equality holds when $b=a$, this can be shown by simple property of similar triangles. But I failed to understand how the upper bound holds in general.

Thanks

Comment: The altitude from A is less than or equal to the  median from A to BC. Do you know the formula for the median from A to BC?

Comment: @peter.petrov, so that implies $h\leq \sqrt{(2b^2+2c^2-a^2)/4}$.

Comment: @ja72, I dont get it. Can you please explain it. It may be obvious, but I still dont get it.

Comment: Are you sure this inequality is true? Can you check that this inequality is indeed what's written in your book?

Comment: The idea is that the equality holds when $b=a$, this can be shown from the property of similar triangles. Otherwise it is upper bounded by the quantity on the right hand side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, this turned out to be trickier than I expected.

Let $\beta$ be the angle at point/vertex B.

One can notice that $\beta \leq \pi /2$ 
(because $b \leq a$).

So the cosine of $\beta$ is non-negative.

The given inequality is equivalent to:

$h_a / c \leq \sqrt{1-\frac{c^2}{4b^2}}$

which is the same as:

$sin(\beta) \leq \sqrt{1-\frac{c^2}{4b^2}}$

which is equivalent to

$sin^2(\beta) \leq 1-\frac{c^2}{4b^2}$

which is equivalent to

$1 - cos^2(\beta) \leq 1-\frac{c^2}{4b^2}$

which is equivalent to

$cos^2(\beta) \geq \frac{c^2}{4b^2}$

Now since $cos(\beta)$ is non-negative this is equivalent to:

$cos(\beta) \geq \frac{c}{2b}$

So the last inequality is what we need to prove.

Let's apply to it the law of cosines:

$(a^2 + c^2 - b^2)/(2ac) \geq \frac{c}{2b}$

After some simple rework, the last one is equivalent to:

$a^2b + c^2b-b^3-ac^2 \geq 0$

i.e. to:

$(a-b)(ab+b^2-c^2) \geq 0$

The last one is obviously true because $c\leq b\leq a$
and so both $(a-b)$ and $(ab+b^2-c^2)$ are non-negative.

So by equivalence the inequality we started with is also true.

When do we reach equality?

1) when $(a-b)=0$ i.e. when $a=b$ (as you noticed)
2) when $(ab+b^2-c^2) = 0$ but OK... this can never be zero because 
$ab > 0$ and $b^2-c^2 \geq 0$

**SIDE NOTE: please check carefully that I didn't make any mistake.**

Comment: Nice answer. But $\beta$ can be greater than $\pi/2$, in case the triangle in obtuse.

Comment: It cannot be greater, because then $\alpha$ also has to be at least $\pi/2$. Remember that you are given $c\leq b\leq a$ so $\alpha$ is the largest angle.

Comment: ok, thanks for the answer

Comment: $\alpha$ is the angle at vertex $A$. $a \geq b$ implies $\alpha \geq \beta$